# Send data from an iPhone to a C#.net application

Tags: c#, iphone, wpf

I am designing a pretty complex WPF application.
A relatively small part of the application is receiving some raw data from a simple iPhone app that I am writing as well.
The data transfer should only be possible when the two parts (the computer with the software installed and the iPhone) are connected to the same network (usually a wifi home network).
Now, what will be the best way implement the listening part of the desktop app ?
Do I have to simple implement a mini server and keep listening to a specific port ? 
Isn't it two big of an overhead ?

Note,
Although sending the data from the iPhone is only going to happen once every couple of hours, I want the application (as long as it open) to immediately respond when it gets the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to host a WCF service in your WPF Application. See [WCF Getting Started Tutorial from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx).

Typically your application would define a service endpoint such as

```
http://localhost/Send_Your_Iphone_Data_here
```

with which your IPhone app would communicate. See also [Scenario Samples : REST and POX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395208%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could use ZeroConf and Apple's Bonjour to discover services on a Local network and set up a connection. Not exactly sure how to implement it in C# but maybe this article titled [Bonjour for .NET](http://deusty.blogspot.com/2008/03/bonjour-for-net.html) may help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Objective-C expert but from a little Googling I found [a discussion and a working example of sending a file and form fields in a single request](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HTTPFileUpload)

On the server, you can pull the data out again on the other side using:

string data = Request.Form["name"];

If you get stuck, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a great tool for sniffing HTTP requests.